# I keep getting a null pointer

Tags: android

Here is all the error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{johnny.newopen/johnny.newopen.easy}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(int)' on a null object reference
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(int)' on a null object reference
                                                            at johnny.newopen.easy.onCreate(easy.java:126)
                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
public class easy extends AppCompatActivity
{
 Button solve;
 private Chronometer chronometer;
 TextView plus1, plus2, minus1, minus2, multy1, multy2, points;
 int p1, p2, m1, m2, mu1, mu2, p, p_ans, m_ans, mu_ans;
 long time;
 private DBHelper mydb;
 boolean check, check1, check2, check3, check4;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_easy);
    mydb = new DBHelper(this);

 if (check1 && check2 && check3) {

        p = p + 60 - (int) time;
    }
    mydb.insertPoints(p);
    points = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.points);
    int x;
    try {
        {x = mydb.getPoints();}
    }
    catch (Exception e) {x=0;}
    points.setText(x);
}
}
```

I keep getting a null pointer for points. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please share the error message (logcat output)

Comment: Also please write class names `easy` with a capital letter `Easy`

Comment: Also please expand your code to incude the surrounding function (probably on create)

Comment: And `setContentView()` and the corresponding layout.

Comment: Is it `points` or `mydb` that is null?

Comment: points is null.

Comment: <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="points:"
        android:textSize="20dp"
         />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/points"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="casual"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>

Comment: You can edit your question to put in the extra information (instead of the comments).

Comment: Put your log here

Comment: i update the question with all the error message

Comment: hey..  Are you setting text before initializing textview?

Comment: Check line 126 of your activity.... logcat is leading to that line

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your TextView is null at the time of setting text. Looking at your code(incomplete yet), your integer x has not been initialized. Try to run app after setting x=0, also try to check id of textView. 
Also you cannot set an integer value to textview, please use `String.valueOf()`

like this : `points.setText(String.valueOf(x))`

Sorry for improper formatting of answer; I will fix it later.

Comment: Also @Yonatan Rotem, as per your logcat; error is in line 126 of your activity

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Id of `TextView` in layout is same as mentioned in activity "(points)" . Also you cannot set an  integer value to `TextView` directly use `String.valueOf()`.

```
points.setText(String.valueOf(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use x.toString() to set the text value of "points". But you should first check that it exists because I think you're getting the wrong id for the TextView.

Answer (score 0):

hey you cannot set int  directly to textview

**Do simply**

```
points.setText(""+x);
```

**It wil avoid null pointer .**

or as Anuj Kumar says you can

**`**points.setText(String.valueOf(x))**`**

Comment: x is an int , it cannot be null